# Ответ с изображением на сообщение пользователя aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Здраствуйте, мне нужно отправить фото в ответ на последнее сообщение от пользователя в *aiogram*. Я пытался использовать

```
await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=photo, caption='текст', parse_mode="Markdown", reply_to_message_id=message.from_user.id)
```

но выдавало ошибку что сообщение не найдено, кто может помочь?

Comment: Приложите полный текст ошибки

Comment: File "C:\Users\grose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 141, in detect
    raise cls(description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Replied message not found

Comment: полный текст не влезает, показал только нижнюю часть

Comment: А зачем параметр `reply_to_message_id`? Он вообще не нужен

Comment: я хочу ответить на сообщение пользователя, отправляя в ответ картинку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему-то в параметр вы указываете message.from_user.id - это id пользователя. Вам же нужно ответить на id сообщения - message.message_id.
Не понял, зачем вам указывать parse_mode (это можно сделать в самом боте, а не в каждом сообщении)

Код будет выглядеть так:

```
await bot.send_photo(
    message.chat.id, photo, caption='текст', 
    reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)
```

Comment: Спасибо, можете сказать, как указать  боте parse_mode?

Comment: Когда создаёшь объект бота - скажем, bot=Bot(token), вписываешь параметром parse_mode (bot=Bot(token, parse_mode='markdown')